# Why won't Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey throw an exception in VS2010 and VS2012?

Tags: .net, exception, registry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VS2010 does not show unhandled exception message in a WinForms Application on a 64-bit version of Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-winforms-application-on-a)

Consider the following code that creates or opens a registry key:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
//...
var registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Some Key");
```

All versions of Visual Studio are running on the same Windows 7 x64 SP1 machine.  If I run it in Visual Studio 2008, it throws a System.UnauthorizedAccessException (unless I start the IDE with the "Run as administrator" option).  In Visual Studio 2010 and 2012, the key fails to get created, but no exception is thrown.  It just silently fails.  Why?

Comment: Are you running VS2008 on the same version of windows as VS2010/12? Which version?

Comment: Sure it is.  The one thing that's special about VS2010 and vS2012.  Registry virtualization is not relevant since VS2005 SP1.